# App works in debug but is crashing on google play version (classpath issue?)

Tags: java, android, google-play

I just posted a very major update to a program I have on google play. Everything works fine locally. But I have received field reports of about 20 or 30 of the following Crash report:

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.twoplay.twoplayer/com.twoplay.twoplayer.TwoPlayer2Activity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.twoplay.twoplayer.TwoPlayer2Activity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.twoplay.twoplayer-1.apk]
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1680)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1784)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:939)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:864)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:622)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.twoplay.twoplayer.TwoPlayer2Activity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.twoplay.twoplayer-1.apk]
at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1672)
... 11 more
```

com.twoplay.twoplayer/com.twoplay.twoplayer.TwoPlayer2Activity is the correct name of the initial startup activity.

I also have a similar crash-dump where one of the app's services successfully starts, but crashes shortly after starting due to a missing class (not the service class itself).

I am using android.support.v4, along with a variety of other private libraries.

The project files have (for all practical purposes) been rebuilt from scratch since 2.0 upgrade. Although the package file name should be correct.

Curious things that I don't entirely understand in the log file:

```
 /data/app/com.twoplay.twoplayer-1.apk
```

Why does "-1" get appended? The actual name of the APK seems to vary from crash dump to crash dump from the field. Sometimes the "-1" is there; sometimes not. e.g. (from other logs):

```
 /data/app/com.twoplay.twoplayer-2.apk
```

I am assuming and hoping that Google Play developer console would not let me update my app if I had signed with an incorrect key. I didn't have any problems uploading.

Obviously, I'm not able to debug this locally, since I can't download my own app from Google Play. (I do hate that).

Any theories, or suggestions on how to approach gratefully appreciated.

Comment: Any luck with this yet? I'm having a similar issue.